# Unix/bash: Reading A List of Files and Merge Them To A File

Tags: file, bash, unix, merge

I'm trying to figure out a script file that takes in a file containing list of files (each line is a path to file i.e. path/to/file) and merge them into a file.

For example:

```
list.text
--
path/to/filename
filename
```

Then call the script like so

> merge_script.sh list.txt final_file.txt

Any help is appreciated. I'm very handicapped with bash script and hope that some unix guru can help me come up with it quickly. Otherwise it will take me a couple hours to do it right (well, assuming that I ever get it right). I have been hunting for some examples and put them together. No luck so far.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
xargs < list.text cat > final_file.txt
```

`xargs` will send the file names from `list.text` to `cat`, in batches (so they won't overflow the command line).  Then `cat` will print the contents of each file, with the output redirected to `final_file.text`.

Comment: I tried to replace the step of creating a file with the list of files with using the output of `find` directly like this:  `xargs < `find . -name "*.txt" | sort` cat > concatentated.out` but I get `ambiguous redirect` - any suggestions?

Comment: How about a simple pipeline, with no redirection?
`find . -name '*.txt' | sort | xargs cat`

Comment: @AdamLiss any way to make it work for files that have special characters in their names, like parenthesis? Thanks!

Comment: @VictorMaiaAldecôa It's bash; there's _always_ a way to do it, if you can figure out how to ask. ️

Here's one option:  
`while read f; do cat "$f"; done < list.txt`  
  
Another one:  
`eval "$(sed 's/.*/cat "&"/' files)"`